# Problema com consulta a banco de dados por data utilizando linq e entity no C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, linq

Tenho a seguinte consulta no banco;

```
consultas = ctx.Consultas.Include(c => c.Cliente).Include(p => p.Procedimento).ToList();
```

que funciona perfeitamente, porem quero incluir um where para filtrar por data de agendamento, já tentei de algumas formas como:

```
consultas = ctx.Consultas.Where(a => a.Inicio.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == entrada).Include(c => c.Cliente).Include(p => p.Procedimento).ToList();`
```

### ou

```
   consultas = ctx.Consultas.Where(a => a.Inicio.Date == DateTime.Parse(entrada)).Include(c => c.Cliente).Include(p => p.Procedimento).ToList();`
```

assim como outras variações como esta, porem meu problema persiste, um retorno de uma lista vazia, este campo no meu banco de dados (mySql) esta na seguinte formatação 2019-05-14 12:30:00 (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), a minha consulta deve desconsiderar o horário, já tentei passar a entrada tanto como string e também dateTime

Comment: Já utilizou o DbFunctions.TruncateTime?

Comment: Olá Lucas esse campo Inicio é um DateTime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas vamos lá vamos ver se consigo te ajudar.

```
consultas = ctx.Consultas.Where(a => a.Inicio.Day == entrada.Day && a.Inicio.Month == entrada.Month && a.Inicio.Year == entrada.Year).Include(c => c.Cliente).Include(p => p.Procedimento).ToList();
```

Comment: Entrada é uma `string`, não tem `Day`, `Month` ou `Year`. Tente evitar o comentário desnecessário no final da resposta. Se você receber um voto negativo, provavelmente é porque tem algo de errado na resposta (o que é o caso agora). Neste caso, dê uma revisada no que foi postado.

Comment: por enquanto foi o único que funcionou

Comment: Olá Lucas que bom que funcionou para você. É para isso que eu ainda entro na comunidade, poder ajudar os outros.@LINQ ainda bem que funcionou e não fui negativado. Boas programações para todos nós.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa 1:

```c#
consultas = ctx.Consultas.Where(a => a.Inicio.Date == entrada.Date)
.Include(c => c.Cliente).Include(p => p.Procedimento).ToList();
```

Alternativa 2:

```c#
consultas = ctx.Consultas.Where(a => a.Inicio.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == entrada.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
.Include(c => c.Cliente).Include(p => p.Procedimento).ToList();
```